# Does Joe start over in “May December” (2023)?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, may-december

In [*May December*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_December) (2023), before graduation, one of Joe's butterflies emerges from its chrysalis. Does this symbolize he is starting over too?

Comment: I think that yes, the film does a lot to point to Natalie Portman's stay having a lasting impact on their relationship, certainly from Joe's perspective of realizing that he has been a victim of child sexual abuse. But it's all up to interpretation at the end of the day.